# CraftCMS - show category of entries fields in content-type

Tags: craftcms

I'm making a website for a bicycleshop.
The shop has different 'frames' and you can 'build' your own bike by choosing a frame and the components you want (groupset, wheel, pedals, ...).

In the back-end I have a content-type 'components' that exist of:

- component-category
- component-title
- component-price

In the content-type 'bike-types' you can add multiple components to the bike-type (frame).

I was wondering whether it's possible to show the category of a component in the overview of the components in a bike-type entry.
Because now it's confusing that you've 'shimano 105' in the 'group' category and 'shimano 105' in the 'pedals' category.

Thanks a lot!
Karlien

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update that components title to be dynamic and have a secondary field for it's actual title.

E.g. the title of the components could be `{customTitle} - {category.title}`

You can do this when editing the entry type.

Comment: I had to 'query' the category title with .one() but works like a charm for my issue. thanks a lot!